# GET http://192.168.1.10/wp/item/kfc/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET VM41:1

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I'm getting this weird error on a page hosted at my local installation of wordpress.. and I have no clue what this could be..

Chrome reports:

```
GET http://192.168.1.10/wp/item/kfc/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET VM41:1
```

I've noticed that with refresh, the last part, here VM41 changes randomly but not the :1

then if i click on the file that chrome marks as non retrievable, it leads to:

```
<script>var ua = navigator.userAgent; var meta = document.createElement('meta');if((ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1 && ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile')) || ((ua.match(/iPhone/i)) || (ua.match(/iPad/i)))){ meta.name = 'viewport'; meta.content = 'target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width'; }var m = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0]; m.parentNode.insertBefore(meta,m);</script>
```

Any ideas?

*Firefox wont open the page either.
 MalwareBytes is installed on the pc, but tried also by disabling it with same results.
 System contains: Php 5.5.10 x64, Apache 2.4.9 x64 & MySql 5.0.11 x64.

Comment: Maybe it is some sort of browser plugin, which Malware bytes install to the browsers, try to disable all plugins there (just to make sure you have no interference) and test again.

Comment: same results. this is absolutely network problem or could be (w)amp and/or code related?

Comment: Is this your local PC you are trying to access, if so, try using `127.0.0.1` as IP

Comment: it will come up with the same error